# Constructing full HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

How can one load a `HTML` file and run `javascript` embedded in it to construct full `HTML` page programatically in the same way as done by browsers?

Edit 1 - I have an application where I am trying to read some data embedded in an html page of a remote website. However, after fetching this page from remote website, I don't see that data because that data is actually loaded by a `javascript` embedded in this HTML page after browser loads initial markup. So, I need a way in my application to trigger `javascript` embedded in the `HTML` page in order to construct full `HTML` page.

Comment: What do you mean load an html file? Is it same domain or cross domain? Some more details please..

Comment: I have added more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have an HTML file stored on your computer, the only way that you can compile it is with your browser. Just enter the absolute file path in your browser's url input. If I misunderstood your question, leave a comment and I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Question needs more details, but depending on what you want:

---

#### If you want to dynamically load different HTML documents, see [iFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

---

#### If you want to insert elements to an empty html document:

First, make a blank html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</html>
```

Then in `main.js` do:

```
var html = document.querySelector('html');
// Append remaining page elements to the html element here.
// (the `head` and `body` elements may have been automatically created)
// You will need createElement and appendChild
```

- [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)